# Finding time complexity of k-ary recursive function

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

Consider the following binary recursive fibonassi program:

```
Algorithm binaryFib(k)  //k is assumed to be non-negative integer
   if (k <= 1)
      return k
   else
      return binaryFib(k-1) + binaryFib(k-2)
end binaryFib
```

The recurrence relation for above is:

T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)

The run time complexity for the same is O(2^n), as can be seen in below pic for n=8:

[image]

However if you look at the bottom of the tree, say by taking n=3, it wont run 2^n times at each level:

[image]

**Q1.** Wont this fact have any effect on time complexity or does the time complexity O(2^n) ignores this fact?

**Q2.** I guess I can rephrase Q1 by eliminating above fact with following recurrence relation: T(n) = 2*T(n-1). Does this recurrence relation still have same O(2^n) time complexity?

**Q3.** Finally I want to generalize: Does the recurrence relation T(n)=k * T(n-1) have O(k^n) time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that this won't run 2<sup>n</sup> times. Though, keep in mind that O(2<sup>n</sup>) is an asymptotic bound and not a tight bound. In order to get a tight bound, you could use generating functions and you would get a complexity of ~ **O(1.618<sup>n</sup>)** for generating the fibonacci sequence.

As for your second question, the complexity for the recurrence relation `T(n) = 2 * T(n-1)` would also have an asymptotic bound of O(2<sup>n</sup>) but in this case it will also be a tight bound. To understand the difference you should think that in the fibonacci sequence we skip one recursion at each level in contrast to the recurrence relation you mentioned in **Q2** (due to T(n-2) instead of T(n-1)).

The recurrence `T(n) = k * T(n-1)` has an asymptotic bound of **O(k<sup>n</sup>)** and you can prove this by induction.